# Setting which single object gets read out by Voiceover when a new UIViewController is presented

Tags: swift, xcode, accessibility, voiceover

I'm building an accessible app in Xcode using Swift.

When my app opens a new page and I am using Accessibility Voiceover it plays out loud 'one' item from the page. This presumably announces to visually impaired people that a new page has appeared. The problem I have is on some pages it selects a strange item to play first. Is there a way to stipulate which item I would like played on each separate UIViewController?

Answer (score 1):

I found that I need to place this in my `viewDidAppear` method:

```
UIAccessibility.post(notification: UIAccessibility.Notification.screenChanged,
                argument: self.firstObject);
```

Full details:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/SupportingAccessibility.html